# how to compare two uneven dataset columns with each other?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

[image]

As shown in the above picture there are two datasets that do not have the same row count. The task is to compare the distance between each city to the range each vehicle can travel i.e. (compare the distance between city1 & city2 with all the vehicle type ranges.)

Comment: You could get the cartesian product of the two dataframes (using merge), this would give you a new dataframe with one line for every combination of vehicle and couple of cities. You could then do the comparison on that dataframe using the Range and Distance columns.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that we have 2 dictionaries(If you have a DataFrame, you can use `to_dict()` method to convert it to the dictionary)

```
vehicles = {'A320': 5000, 'A330': 8000, 'B737': 5000, 'B747': 10000, 'Q400': 1500, 'ATR72': 1000}
city_distances = {'AA-BB': 3000, 'BB-CC': 6500, 'CC-AA': 400, 'AA-DD': 1000}
```

You can simply create a nested for loop and check whatever condition you want. I, for example, did check, whether the vehicle could travel the city route.

```
for city_route in city_distances.keys():
    for vehicle in vehicles.keys():
        if vehicles[vehicle] >= city_distances[city_route]:
            print(f'Vehile {vehicle} can travel the {city_route} route')
        else:
            print(f"Vehile {vehicle} can't travel the {city_route} route")
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you didn't tell/show us the expected output, so I'll give you the code to let you `.merge()` both DF, from there you can do pretty everything you want:

```
df3 = df2.merge(df1, how='cross')
df3
```

Truncated result:

| index | city_a | city_b | vehicles | range |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | AA-BB | 3000 | A320 | 5000 |
| 1 | AA-BB | 3000 | A330 | 8000 |
| 2 | AA-BB | 3000 | B737 | 5000 |
| 3 | AA-BB | 3000 | B747 | 10000 |
| 4 | AA-BB | 3000 | Q400 | 1500 |
| 5 | AA-BB | 3000 | ATR72 | 1000 |
| 6 | BB-CC | 6500 | A320 | 5000 |
| 7 | BB-CC | 6500 | A330 | 8000 |

...

| index | city_a | city_b | vehicles | range |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 16 | CC-AA | 400 | Q400 | 1500 |
| 17 | CC-AA | 400 | ATR72 | 1000 |
| 18 | AA-DD | 1000 | A320 | 5000 |
| 19 | AA-DD | 1000 | A330 | 8000 |
| 20 | AA-DD | 1000 | B737 | 5000 |
| 21 | AA-DD | 1000 | B747 | 10000 |
| 22 | AA-DD | 1000 | Q400 | 1500 |
| 23 | AA-DD | 1000 | ATR72 | 1000 |